# How to get a single element by its _id from an array of objects which is inside another object coming from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a Mongoose schema that allowed me to save a whole JSON object which contains an array of objects (those objects have the _ids I want), but when I try to get one user from router.get express (I'm using findById), it returns null, when I do a get petition getting the whole data (using find() method) it looks like this:

thanks to all of you, English is not my first language, sorry for whatever grammar mistake that I could've made

```
[
   {
    "_id": "6384db62827c2f0816944734",
    "arrayData": [

      {
        "description": "KEYCAPS",
        "price": "$99.00",
        "img": "link,of.the.image",
        "_id": "6384db62827c2f0816944735"
      },
      {
        "description": "KEYCAPS",
        "price": "$99.00",
        "img": "link,of.the.image2",
        "_id": "7454db62827c2f0816912345"
      }

      ]
   }
 ]
```

I've tried other ways of getting the ids, to be honest I've been coding just for a couple of months, I'm a little shy of showing it but I believe this is the code I need to change

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  
    const { id } = req.params;
  
    userSchema
        .findById(id)
        .then((data) => {res.json(data)})
    .catch((err) => res.json({message: err}))
})
```

by the way my request.http enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec87N.png)